# How to replace nested .then() function in bookshelf

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I am new to node.js and I am having trouble with removing multiple nested .then() inside of a bookshelf.js function.

The code below is what I am working on right now. And it works fine for now but I need to add more than 20+ nested .then() to finish the project. Therefore, I am trying to replace .then() to some other method before it gets crazy.

Any help or tip would be appreciated.

```
   getItem: function (req, res, next) {

        DepartmentCollection.forge()
        .fetch({
              debug: true     
        })
        .then(function(collection) {
             new GlossaryTerm({'GlossaryTermID': req.params.id}).fetch({
                    withRelated: ['department'],
                    debug: true     
           })
              .then(function(model) {
                    if ("undefined" === typeof collection) { console.log("step 2: variable is undefined") }
                    else { console.log("step 2: variable is defined") };

                    res.render('glossary/glossary-term-detail',{domain:'GlossaryTerm', title: 'Glossary Term Detail',
                                                                  data: model, department_data: collection }); 

              }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    res.send('An error occured');
              }); 

        }).catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
              res.send('An error occured');
        });

  }
```

Comment: why more than 20 then()? do you have more than 20 promises to resolve?

Comment: yes, i need to add 20+ more promise.then() to finish the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you do not need to nest thenables. The result of a thenable becomes the input for the next one. So most times you can **chain** them instead of *nesting*:

```
getItem: function (req, res, next) {
  // Creating a closure for storing intermediate then() results
  let collection;
  // Making getItem() a promise itself
  return DepartmentCollection
    .forge()
    .fetch({
      debug: true     
    })
    .then(function(fetched_collection) {
      collection = fetched_collection;
      if ("undefined" === typeof collection) { 
        console.log("step 2: variable is undefined")
      } else { 
        console.log("step 2: variable is defined")
      }
      return new GlossaryTerm({'GlossaryTermID': req.params.id})
        .fetch({
                withRelated: ['department'],
                debug: true     
        });
    })    
    .then(function(model) {
      res.render('glossary/glossary-term-detail', {
        domain:'GlossaryTerm', 
        title: 'Glossary Term Detail',
        data: model, 
        department_data: collection }); 
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
        res.send('An error occured');
    }); 
}
```

An exception is when the logic must be split into more chains that provide a result using different ways. In these cases it is advisable to move the complex logic to another function (returning a promise):

so this

```
function complex() {
  return f1()
    .then(x => {
      if (!x) {
        return f2()
          .then(f3);
      }
      return f3();
    })
    .then(...);      
}
```

becomes this:

```
function complex() {
  function f4(x) {
    if (!x) {
      return f2()
        .then(f3);
    }
    return f3();
  }
  return f1()
    .then(f4)
    .then(...);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend the [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) library.

```
npm install co --save
```

Then you can make these calls 'appear' synchronous and avoid some of this pyramid of doom type problem.

```
const co = require('co');

co(function* () {
  const resultOne = yield asyncCallOne();
  const resultTwo = yield asyncCallTwo();

  try {
    const resultThree = yield asyncCallThree();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  // and so on, and so on.
});
```